# Compiling a c++ code into a single package containing all dependencies

Tags: c++, compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a cpp project that uses several libraries to which I have both *.so and *.a libraries. How should I compile my code to produce a self-containing library that doesn't require the user to install the dependencies ( and preferably hides dependencies from the user) ?

Let's assume code is c.cpp and libraries are liba.so and libb.so.
Goal to have a libc.so (or libc.a) with liba.so and libb.so transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is static linking. Since you mention that you have the archive version of the library, it should work. Try using the `-static` flag with gcc for this.